# Tosca commander unable to identify drop down box created using PrimeNG ?How can we do that?

Tags: automation, tosca

While doing xscan-->HTML, Tosca commander is not identifying dropdown box created using prime NG. Is there anyway we can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdowns you are trying to capture are like the example provided at the [PrimeNg website](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown), they could be captured by XScan after implementing a custom extension so that Tosca can recognize the PrimeNg implementation of a combobox as a combobox with Tosca Commander.

This requires creating a .NET project and writing code outside of Tosca.  Tricentis' Automation Engineer 2 course covers building custom controls in greater detail, but it is one of their more advanced courses with several prerequisites and requiring a developer skillset.

The [TBox API Manual](https://documentation.tricentis.com/devcorner/1400/tboxapi/index.html#topic1.html) also provides an example implementation of a custom combobox:

[Implementing a ComboBox](https://documentation.tricentis.com/devcorner/1400/tboxapi/index.html#topic39.html)